# optimize shadow rendering

Tags: html, css

Do you have any ideas how to improve shadow rendering performance?

whenever, I apply

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 
-moz-box-shadow:
box-shadow:
```

The browser resource usage dramatically increases.

I draw div shadow working with `transform()`.

From my testing, Chrome performs fastest compared to Firefox and Safari. For IE and the rest browsers, I have not tested yet.

Comment: Best not to keep people guessing chum - in what way are you applying these, and in what browser are you seeing performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888 !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888 !important;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888 !important;
```